# Function as left operand - What do I do?

Tags: visual-c++

As much as I searched for answers, I can't quite understand any of them, so I decided to ask for direct help.

Basically, this program is supposed to read each digit of the number and then write it down normally. for now this is a 'skeleton' code as I am trying to get the main idea of how to program it further, but I am already stumbling upon errors.

I get an error in whichever line of **switch** function I use, yet I don't know how to solve it. I get an error **error C2659: '=': function as left operand**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int number, digit;
int i;
string word[4];

void lowering();
void units();
void tens();

int main()
{
i = 4;
    word[i];

cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> number;
cout << endl;

lowering();
units();
i--;
lowering();
tens();

for(int x = 4; x >=0; x--)
    cout << word[x];

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void lowering()
{
    digit = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
}

void units()
{
    switch (digit)
    {
    case 1:
        word[i].append = " one"; break;
    case 2:
        word[i].append = " two"; break;
    case 3:
        word[i].append = " three"; break;
    case 4:
        word[i].append = " four"; break;
    case 5:
        word[i].append = " five"; break;
    case 6:
        word[i].append = " six"; break;
    case 7:
        word[i].append = " seven"; break;
    case 8:
        word[i].append = " eight"; break;
    case 9:
        word[i].append = " nine"; break;
    default:
        word[i].append = "";
    }

    word[i].append = " ";
}

void tens()
{
    switch (digit)
    {
    case 1:
        word[i].append = " ten"; break;
    case 2:
        word[i].append = " twenty "; break;
    case 3:
        word[i].append = " thirty "; break;
    case 4:
        word[i].append = " fourty"; break;
    case 5:
        word[i].append = " fifty"; break;
    case 6:
        word[i].append = " sixty"; break;
    case 7:
        word[i].append = " seventy"; break;
    case 8:
        word[i].append = " eighty"; break;
    case 9:
        word[i].append = " ninety"; break;
    default:
        word[i].append = "";
    }

    word[i].append = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your switch cases, you should use this:

```
void units()
{
    switch (digit)
    {
    case 1:
        word[i].append(" one"); break;
    case 2:
        word[i].append(" two"); break;
    case 3:
        word[i].append(" three"); break;
    case 4:
        word[i].append(" four"); break;
    case 5:
        word[i].append(" five"); break;
    case 6:
        word[i].append(" six"); break;
    case 7:
        word[i].append(" seven"); break;
    case 8:
        word[i].append(" eight"); break;
    case 9:
        word[i].append(" nine"); break;
    default:
        word[i].append("");
    }

    word[i].append(" ");
}
```

Besides for better code quality, you should put the `break;` into a new line.

Comment: I'll take a look at your solution later, but thanks for the response.
I know that     break;      should be put into a new line for nicer view, but I just thought that the function would look bloated out as it had to be repeated a few times further on.

Comment: Okay, it works. Now I have another problem though, but I'll try to solve it on my own for a while before asking for help again ^^"